# Sintaxe correta para SELECT e INNER JOIN no Zend

Tags: mysql, select, zend

Acredito que seja uma dúvida simples, mas por não conhecer 50% do Zend estou quebrando a cabeça, então lá vai:

```
$sql =  $db->select()
    ->distinct()
    ->from(array('cli' => 'fc_cblcli'),array('codigo','tipo','nome'))
    ->join(array('poi' => 'fc_log_pointing'),'cli.codigo = poi.codigo')
    ->where('poi.data > ?',$diaIntervalo) //Pega a data em 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
    ->where('poi.codigo = cli.codigo')
    ->order('poi.codigo ASC')
    ->order('cli.tipo ASC');
```

Estou fazendo um SELECT DISTINCT mas por causa do apelido `poi` está trazendo resultados repetidos de logs.

Na parte do JOIN o apelido `poi` entra na sintaxe da query como mostra no *print($sql);* que eu fiz:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cli`.`codigo`, `cli`.`tipo`, `cli`.`nome`, `poi`.* 
FROM `fc_cblcli` AS `cli` 
INNER JOIN `fc_log_pointing` AS `poi` ON cli.codigo = poi.codigo WHERE (poi.data > '2014-11-19 17:16:28') 
    AND (poi.codigo = cli.codigo) 
ORDER BY `poi`.`codigo` ASC, `cli`.`tipo` ASC
```

No lugar do **'poi'** deveria ser **'cli'**, mas da forma que está a sintaxe no Zend não consigo encontrar uma solução para modificar isso sem arruinar o resto.

Se alguém conseguir me explicar a lógica do porque bulhufas está pegando este apelido do JOIN no SELECT eu agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O terceiro parâmetro do join diz quais valores da tabela você quer trazer. Se você não passar nenhum valor, ele traz todos. Por isso existe `poi.*` no resultado final.

Se você não quer trazer nenhuma informação da tabela `fc_log_pointing`, você pode passar `array()` como terceiro parâmetro do `join`, da seguinte forma

```
$sql =  $db->select()
    ->distinct()
    ->from(array('cli' => 'fc_cblcli'),array('codigo','tipo','nome'))
    ->join(array('poi' => 'fc_log_pointing'),'cli.codigo = poi.codigo',array())
    ->where('poi.data > ?',$diaIntervalo) _//Pega a data em 'yyyy-MM-dd'_
    ->where('poi.codigo = cli.codigo')
    ->order('poi.codigo ASC')
    ->order('cli.tipo ASC');
```

Comment: era realmente isso que estava acontecendo! Estava pegando todas as colunas por falta deste terceiro parâmetro. Obrigado.